# Can I configure specific version of node to run when I use jest?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ldap

I have a lambda with JS in NodeJS with 14.x Runtime.
Version of jest is 24.9

I have a function that uses activedirectory (0.7.2) dependency.
When I run test on my machine with node v12.16.1 it fails with

```
 Details:

    C:\...\...\...\...\...\node_modules\@ldapjs\messages\lib\ldap-message.js:27
        this.#messageId = parseInt(options.messageId ?? options.messageID ?? '1', 10)
                                                      ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@ldapjs/messages/index.js:5:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ldapjs/lib/messages/index.js:3:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ldapjs/lib/errors/index.js:6:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/request-queue/purge.js:3:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/request-queue/index.js:5:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:3:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/index.js:4:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ldapjs/lib/index.js:5:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/activedirectory/lib/activedirectory.js:3:12)
```

But, when I run with node v14.16.1 it runs OK.
Serverless is configured with provider runtime: nodejs14.x

When lambda is deployed on Jenkins, fails with same error
What can I do to run tests successfully?

I tried to add into jest config:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!activedirectory)"
    ]
```

Comment: Can you show your full jest config?

Comment: Sure: `"jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/test/utils/"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "index.{ts,js}",
      "Business/**/*.{ts,js}",
      "libs/**/*.{ts,js}",
      "middlewares/**/*.{ts,js}",
      "models/**/*.{ts,js}",
      "routes/**/*.{ts,js}",
      "schemas/**/*.{ts,js}"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!activedirectory)"
    ]
  }`